# Why am I getting a compile error when multiplying a decimal by a literal value?

Tags: c#, decimal

When I try to set the `z` variable in the code below, I get this compile time error:

> Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'

```
decimal x = 1, y = 2, z;

// There are two ways I set the z variable:
z = (x*y)*(.8 * 1.732050808m);
z = (1000 * x)/(y * 1.732050808m)* .8;
```

Why is that, and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Be sure to use `.8m` instead of `.8`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was secretly hoping it wasn't that simple. : )

Comment: m forces the literal to be interpreted as a decimal.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say which line it was, but I'm betting on these two:

```
z = (x*y)*(.8 * 1.732050808m);
```

And:

```
z = (1000 * x)/(y * 1.732050808m)* .8;
```

Note that your .8 does not have the 'm' qualifier. Every other place I see you did supply that.

Answer (score 3):

In this line here:

z = (x*y)*(.8 * 1.732050808m);

you specify .8 as a literal, but without the 'm' suffix, the literal specifies a double.

z = (x*y)*(.8m * 1.732050808m);

will fix it.