# Multiplying TextBox to a Value

Tags: c#, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, Operator ‘*’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘double’ and ‘decimal’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363706/c-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-double-and-decimal)

Hi i want to Multiply the value that inserted in the textbox but i getting error. Here's my Code.

```
decimal num1, num2;
if(decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out num1) 
   && decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out num2)){

 decimal ans = num1 * 0.20 + num2 * 0.20;
 Label1.Text = ans.ToString();

        }else{
            MessageBox.Show("Please Put a number!! ");
        }
```

I'm having error in "ans" please help me. This my error "Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and double;"

Comment: Jay, what is the error message?

Comment: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and double;

Comment: Then, this is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363706/c-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-double-and-decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363706/c-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-double-and-decimal)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the compiler sees the constants as `Double`.
To fix the error itself you can either cast the constants to decimal like this:

```
decimal ans = num1 * (decimal)0.20 + num2 * (decimal)0.20;
```

Or even better (as stated in the comments) you can just [specify the type of the constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/166762/1379664)

```
decimal ans = num1 * 0.20m + num2 * 0.20m;
```

Comment: Why casting constants instead of [making them of the right type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/166762/11683) in the first place? It may even [be harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166752/c-sharp-compiler-number-literals/166762#comment6475244_166809).

Comment: GSerg is right, no casting needed. Look what Hamlet Hakobyan wrote

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal ans = num1 * 0.20m + num2 * 0.20m;
```